# What is the asymptotic growth rate of divisor function with k=-1?

Tags: number-theory

What is the asymptotic growth rate (big O notation) the divisor function $σ_{-1}(n)$ ?
Couldn't find any discussion on Wikipedia for cases involving k=-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $$\sigma_{-1}(n) = \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d}  = \sum_{d|n} \frac{d}{n} =\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$$ so you can just study the asymptotics of $\sigma(n)$ and divide by $n$.